# Error using TCMUpload assembly

Tags: 2013-sp1

I am facing issue while using TCMUpload assembly to upload any dll on CME. TCMUpload assembly is throwing 404 error for AssemblyTemplateUploadWebService.asmx. I can execute the service from browser but TCMupload assembly is not able to hit the service.

Is this some kind of installation issue OR is it any license issue?

Comment: What are the Tridion event logs telling you, and the windows application event logs?

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting in the Event Logs and can you ensure the user you are using to execute the TCMUploadAssembly have all the necessary permissions? Did you tried with running it "As Administrator"

Comment: Pankaj- No Eror are getting logged in system. I am getting error on console itself.